# FOR command not executing in script

Tags: batch-file

I receive files via FTP that are placed in a folder called Landing. These files arrive in a folder that is randomly named, for example `000174`, and the files inside are named `Activity.txt.174` for example.

I have created a small script that allows me to reduce the file name to `Activity.txt` which works perfectly fine when executed within a command shell but when saved as a batch file it will not execute.

The script line is:

```
FOR /R %f IN (*.txt.*) DO REN "%f" *.&
```

I have attempted to add various triggers from other scripts to get this working but when I get this working via CMD it still will not execute from a batch file.

Can anyone help please.

Mike

Comment: Change `%f` to `%%f` when put in batch file.

Comment: Please consider reading the help file for the command you are trying to use before asking a question.  You can do this by opening a command prompt and typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark. example: `for /?`. The eighth line of the help file says **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.**

Answer (score 1):

Change 
 `FOR /R %f IN (*.txt.*) DO REN "%f" *.&` 
to 
`FOR /R %%f IN (*.txt.*) DO REN "%%f" *.&`

https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: Please do not answer, very basic duplicate questions.

Comment: Jerry Thank you so much for that. The shocking thing is I tried this by pasting it into the CMD prompt and it failed. Seems the %%f only works for when its executed as a batch file.

Comment: @Shattered, as I stated in my comment below your question.

Comment: Correct @Shattered, this will only work as a batch file. If this was correct (and it is not closed as duplicate), please mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use double percent sign before your variable name.

Batch script

```
@echo off
FOR /R HERE_YOUR_ROOT_PATH %%f IN (*.txt.*) DO REN "%%f" *.& 
@echo on
```

Comment: Please do not answer, very basic duplicate questions, _more especially when the same answer has already been provided_.

Comment: The question was already answered 17 minutes before your answer and has not provided anymore additional information that what the previous answer did.

Comment: Sorry if this was a duplicate question, I did a search but must have missed it. No offence meant. Its just sometimes hard to see the forest.

Comment: @Shattered you didn't need to search at all.  All you had to do was read the help file for the `FOR` command.

Comment: Sorry for duplicating answer, but when I was testing my solution @Jerry M. post his answer and I wasn't see it